# Electron "Network service crashed, restarting service."

Tags: node.js, linux, electron, chromium

Sporadically, when I run Electron inside a Docker container, I get the following error:

```
[15:1102/154337.143944:ERROR:network_service_instance_impl.cc(333)] Network service crashed, restarting service.
```

Which causes partially rendering of the front-end application that is loaded with `win.loadURL` on localhost

The issue seems very similar to https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=268123, but nothing from the suggestions works.

Running latest Electron `15.0.2` and Chromedriver `95.0.0`

Also, when closing the Electron window, I get an error

```
Error: ERR_FAILED (-2) loading 'https://localhost:{port}/{path_to}/index.html'
    at rejectAndCleanup (node:electron/js2c/browser_init:165:7486)
    at Object.stopLoadingListener (node:electron/js2c/browser_init:165:7861)
    at Object.emit (node:events:394:28) {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ERR_FAILED',
  url: 'https://localhost:{port}/{path_to}/index.html'
} [EOL]
```

Which is caught inside the main.js when executing await `win.loadURL(url)`

Also, in the console log of the Electron browser window, this error appears:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk 108 failed.
(timeout: https://localhost:{port}/{path_to}/108.da4993913b4a27951976.js)
ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk 108 failed.
```

Anyone encountered this issue before?

Comment: I had the same issue once, but it disappeared after PC restart and I cannot reproduce it again.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find what triggers the issue, not yet the root cause.

I commented out the `setCertificateVerifyProc` Electron hook and the issue seemed to not be appearing anymore.

```
// win.webContents.session.setCertificateVerifyProc((request, callback) => {
//   callback(-3);  
// });
```

In the [Electron docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/session#sessetcertificateverifyprocproc) there is an interesting note stating:

```
NOTE: The result of this procedure is cached by the network service.
```

Which is practically reflecting on the logs

```
network_service_instance_impl.cc(333)] Network service crashed
```

If you need more info on this issue, please follow the official Electron Github issue page https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/31675